# Error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning trying to testing

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

i get this error when try run my test:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefine
```

i just need that "captcha" get true result. Any change that I have applied to my code gives me the same result, I tried removing the asynchronous functions, but I still have the same problem.

here my testing code:

```
import proxyquire from 'proxyquire';
import assert from 'assert';
import chai from 'chai';
const expect = chai.expect;

const loggerStub ={
  log:()=>{
  return;
  }
}

const lodashStub = ()=>{
 result = undefined;
}
const validationStub = {
  validation:()=>{
   return Promise.resolve({
   data:{
     success:true
        }
      });
     }
    }

const req = {
 body:{
 captchaResponse: true
   }
  }

 const res = {
  status: (status) => {
   return {
   send: () => {
    return;
    }
   }
  }
 }

 describe('Probando captcha', ()=>{
 describe('Validación de captcha', ()=>{
  it('Captcha validado OK', (done)=>{
    const captcha = proxyquire('../src/controllers/captcha',{
      '../domain/captcha': validationStub,
      '../core/logger': loggerStub,
      'lodash': lodashStub
    });
    const next = () => {
      console.log('llegó al next');
      expect(captcha.validation()).to.be.true;
      done();
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      captcha.validation(req, res, next);
    }, 200);
   });
 });
});
```

here my code:

```
import { get } from "lodash";
import captcha from "../domain/captcha";
import logger from "../core/logger";
require("babel-polyfill");

const validation = async (req, res, next) => {
 if (!req.body.captchaResponse) {
  logger.log("info", "MISSING CAPTCHA PARAMETERS");
  return res.status(422).send();
 }
 const captchaResponse = req.body.captchaResponse;
 console.log(req.body.captchaResponse);

 try {

   const result = await captcha.validation(captchaResponse);
    if (get(result, "data.success")) {
     logger.log("info", "CAPTCHA VALIDATION OK");
     next();
     return;
   } else {
   logger.log("info", "FAIL CAPTCHA VALIDATION");
  return res.status(422).send();
  }
 } catch (e) {
 console.log(e);
 logger.log("info", "ERROR CAPTCHA VALIDATION");
 return res.status(422).send();
 }
};

export default { validation };
```

My package.json test:

"test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register babel-polyfill ./test/ --
 recursive"

Comment: Where is thy **body-parser**, sir? I suppose you are missing it. May the [force link](https://hashnode.com/post/why-am-i-getting-reqbody-as-undefined-in-express-ciu8ecx4k04lhza53vc2hqv64) be with you.

Comment: @oneturkmen i used body-parser, but the same result, console.log(req.body.captchaResponse) returned true

Comment: can you remove the following line `expect(captcha.validation()).to.be.true` and see it works

Comment: @oneturkmen yes! it works! but why???

Comment: Then, thou forgot to include `(req, res, next)` args into the `(captcha.validation())`.

Comment: See the answer and please accept it, if it truly works for you.

Comment: @oneturkmen you say like this? : expect(captcha.validation(req, res, next)).to.be.true; this make crush my cli, i don't know if i wrote wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159194/discussion-between-oneturkmen-and-alvaro-vergara).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line in the definition of `next ()` causes problems

```
expect(captcha.validation()).to.be.true;
```

You either need to include `req, res, next` into `captcha.validation()`, or remove this line at all.

**Why?** Because function expects three arguments, and as it gets none, you get *undefined* on *req.body*.

Comment: you say like this? : expect(captcha.validation(req, res, next)).to.be.true; this make crush my cli, i don't know if i wrote wrong